# Finding Selenium element with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to interact with a website sections but the class name is the same for all of them and all i have is the title name of the desired section but nothing else so how do i interact with this element i have tried find_element_by_link_text but it does not seem to work with this website

Comment: Try reading about `xpath` and `css selector`. Also it would be impossible for anyone to help you with code if you don't give a concrete example like in this case sharing the link to the page you are trying to extract.

Comment: we can help you better if you share the element you want to choose with us